# PHP Logical Mathematics (If/Else)

Tags: php, math, logic, subtraction

A type of logic when determining the value of numbers that I frequently have to deal with (I'm sure we all do), is reducing a number if it is larger than another number.

My current example is this:

```
$position = (int) $x; // Position in stream
$length   = (int) $y; // Byte length in stream
$amount   = (int) $z; // Amount of bytes to read

// Convert to single equation.
// ===================================================
$available = $length - $position;
$amount = $amount > $available ? $available : $amount;
// ===================================================

// Possible solution, but uses logic
// $amount = $amount > ($available = $length - $position) ? $available : $amount;

// doRead($amount)
```

I have put my "default" solution beneath the initial assignments, and my shortened (but ultimately the same) solution in a comment below it.

I am looking for a mathematical solution i.e. a single equation, where the `$amount` will equal the result of `$length - $position` if it is greater than that subtraction, else it will remain unchanged.

Comment: `$amount = min($available, $amount);`

Comment: @MarkBaker Elegant `$amount = min($length - $position, $amount);`.  Although there is likely an answer here to finding the smallest of several values, I like this one because it highlights my ignorance of the simple things.